# Convex sets and their extreme points

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex set and let $M$ be the set of extreme points of $C$ (and thus $C$ is the convex hull of $M$). Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be another convex set. It is known that $C\cap S$ is also convex.

Let $N$ denote the set of extreme points of $C\cap S$. Is it true that $N\subseteq M\cap S$?

PS. This seems to be a basic question regarding the convex set, while after some effort of research, I cannot find a solution. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: 1. $C$ need not be the convex hull of its extreme points.  For example, $C$ a half-space. 2. If $S$ is the unit disk in the plane and $C$ is the disk of radius $2$ in the plane, you will see that $N\subseteq M$ is not true.

Comment: What is true is that any extreme point of $C$ that is in $S$ is an extreme point of $C \cap S$, i.e. $M \cap S \subseteq N$.